# Bash alias parameter inside single+double quotes

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

I am trying to create an alias for creating a GitHub repo using the terminal and the command to do so is `curl -u 'username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"repo_name"}'`

I've defined a function inside my .zshrc file gitcreate() that is supposed to create a GitHub repo using the first parameter as its name

```
gitcreate() {
  curl -u 'my_gh_username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$1"}'
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error:

```
{
   "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
   "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

I've tried escaping the $ and other suggestions I read online but nothing worked and I was hoping someone has a simple solution to this/can refer me to somewhere I might be able to find an answer. thanks!

Comment: Research the difference between single and double quotes. How does `echo "$var"` differ from `echo '$var'`?

Comment: Are you asking about [tag:bash] or [tag:zsh]? You can't be using both at the same time.

Comment: With the GitHub CLI, it would be `gh repo create "$1"` (see [here](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create)).

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
"{\"name\":\"$1\"}"
```

or

```
'{"name":"'"$1"'"}'
```

but at best would be to use proper JSON tool:

```
data=$(jq -n --arg arg "$1" '{"name": $arg}')
curl ...  "$data"
```

Comment: the second suggestion worked perfectly, thanks!